# xUnit AutoFixture throwing error with data annotation attribute

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

I am using `AutoFixture.Xunit2` and try to generate auto data for my model class which has enum with regular expression data annotation as well.

```cs
public enum TypeEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Fix")]
    On = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Not Fix")]
    Off = 1
}

public class DataModel
{
    [RegularExpression("Fix|Not Fix", ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am using `[AutoData]` attribute to generate data for my `DataModel`,

```cs
public class ServiceTest
{
    public readonly Service _sut;
    private readonly Mock<IServiceClient> _serviceClientMock = new Mock<IServiceClient>();
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<Service>> _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<Service>>();
    public ServiceTest()
    {
        _sut = new Service(_serviceClientMock.Object, _loggerMock.Object);
    }

    [Theory]
    [AutoData]
    public async Task Do_Test_For_DoMethod(DataModel model)
    {
        await _sut.DoMethod(model);
    }
}
```

But the test is fail with below error,

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Library.API.Data.Models.TypeEnum'.

1. How to fix this? If I removed `RegularExpression` attribute from the model class, it's works.
2. Plus how to make use to AutoFixture `AtoMoq` feature here to get rid of `Service` class creation with constructor?

**Update**
I tried this way where `TypeEnum` I am providing through `InlineData` and `Id` is auto generated, any other way?

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(TypeEnum.On)]
[InlineData(TypeEnum.Off)]
public async Task Do_Test_For_DoMethod(TypeEnum typeEnum)
{
    var model = new Fixture().Build<DataModel>()
    .With(a => a.Type, typeEnum).Create();

    await _sut.DoMethod(model);
}
```

Comment: Trying to search for `RegularExpression` in AutoFixture codebase and cannot find it ever used in combination with enum. Looks like it's not implemented. (https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/search?q=RegularExpression)

Comment: @Serhii Shushliapin, I tried to create data for enum through `InlineData`, while other will be auto data, see my update. Still looking for some better solution

Comment: The only better way, than the one you found, is to create your own relay for the regular expression attribute that will take into consideration the `DisplayName` attribute on the `enum` types. That is until I the `Frozen` attribute will work on inline parameters.

Comment: @Andrei Ivascu, no following you fully, can you show some code around it?